# DataFrames are not equal after applying groupby but I can't tell why

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I apologize for the wall of code that follows, and for the poor formatting. I tried as many ways as I could think of to find what was causing these dataframes to return False when I applied either DataFrame.equals() or later df1 == df2. I can't find any discrepancies between them.

I got the second dataframe (dftest) by applying groupby to the first (bdf) on all columns except ORDER_QTY. Since the number of rows is the same for both these dataframes I assumed nothing changed (which didn't surprise me.) However, to be sure I compared them using bdf.equals(dftest) and it returned false. This was after I had made sure that the columns were in the correct order. The only other thing I noticed is that the dataframes are not the same size. Otherwise I'm lost...

```
In:
dftest = bdf.groupby(['SITE', 'CUST', 'ORDER_NUMBER', 'ORDER_DATE', 'PURCHASE_ORDER', 'CHANNEL', 'SHIP_TO', 'PROD_LINE', 'GROUP_NUMBER', 'DESCRIPTION', 'ITEM', 'FW_END_DT', 'BPS_INCLUDE']).sum().reset_index()
dftest = dftest[['SITE', 'CUST', 'ORDER_NUMBER', 'ORDER_DATE', 'PURCHASE_ORDER', 'CHANNEL', 'SHIP_TO', 'PROD_LINE', 'GROUP_NUMBER', 'DESCRIPTION', 'ITEM', 'ORDER_QTY', 'FW_END_DT', 'BPS_INCLUDE']]

print(bdf.equals(dftest))
print(bdf.columns)
print(dftest.columns)


Out:
False
Index(['SITE', 'CUST', 'ORDER_NUMBER', 'ORDER_DATE', 'PURCHASE_ORDER',
       'CHANNEL', 'SHIP_TO', 'PROD_LINE', 'GROUP_NUMBER', 'DESCRIPTION',
       'ITEM', 'ORDER_QTY', 'FW_END_DT', 'BPS_INCLUDE'],
      dtype='object')
Index(['SITE', 'CUST', 'ORDER_NUMBER', 'ORDER_DATE', 'PURCHASE_ORDER',
       'CHANNEL', 'SHIP_TO', 'PROD_LINE', 'GROUP_NUMBER', 'DESCRIPTION',
       'ITEM', 'ORDER_QTY', 'FW_END_DT', 'BPS_INCLUDE'],
      dtype='object')
```

^Columns seem to be the same, but `bdf.equals(dftest)` yields False

```
In:
bdf.info()
dftest.info()


Out:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 53025 entries, 0 to 53024
Data columns (total 14 columns):
SITE              53025 non-null object
CUST              53025 non-null object
ORDER_NUMBER      53025 non-null object
ORDER_DATE        53025 non-null datetime64[ns]
PURCHASE_ORDER    53025 non-null object
CHANNEL           53025 non-null object
SHIP_TO           53025 non-null object
PROD_LINE         53025 non-null object
GROUP_NUMBER      53025 non-null object
DESCRIPTION       53025 non-null object
ITEM              53025 non-null object
ORDER_QTY         53025 non-null int64
FW_END_DT     53025 non-null datetime64[ns]
BPS_INCLUDE       53025 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), int64(2), object(10)
memory usage: 6.1+ MB
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 53025 entries, 0 to 53024
Data columns (total 14 columns):
SITE              53025 non-null object
CUST              53025 non-null object
ORDER_NUMBER      53025 non-null object
ORDER_DATE        53025 non-null datetime64[ns]
PURCHASE_ORDER    53025 non-null object
CHANNEL           53025 non-null object
SHIP_TO           53025 non-null object
PROD_LINE         53025 non-null object
GROUP_NUMBER      53025 non-null object
DESCRIPTION       53025 non-null object
ITEM              53025 non-null object
ORDER_QTY         53025 non-null int64
FW_END_DT     53025 non-null datetime64[ns]
BPS_INCLUDE       53025 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), int64(2), object(10)
memory usage: 5.7+ MB
```

^Everything looks the same except the size, as I mentioned.

```
In:
common = bdf.merge(dftest,on=['SITE', 'CUST', 'ORDER_NUMBER', 'ORDER_DATE', 'PURCHASE_ORDER', 'CHANNEL', 'SHIP_TO', 'PROD_LINE', 'GROUP_NUMBER', 'DESCRIPTION', 'ITEM', 'ORDER_QTY', 'FW_END_DT', 'BPS_INCLUDE'], how='outer', indicator=True)
print(common[common['_merge'] != 'both'])



Out:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [SITE, CUST, ORDER_NUMBER, ORDER_DATE, PURCHASE_ORDER, CHANNEL, SHIP_TO, PROD_LINE, GROUP_NUMBER, DESCRIPTION, ITEM, ORDER_QTY, FW_END_DT, BPS_INCLUDE, _merge]
Index: []
```

Tried merging and selecting rows not in both df

```
In:
bdf[(~bdf.SITE.isin(common.SITE))&(~bdf.CUST.isin(common.CUST))&(~bdf.ORDER_NUMBER.isin(common.ORDER_NUMBER))&(~bdf.ORDER_DATE.isin(common.ORDER_DATE))&(~bdf.PURCHASE_ORDER.isin(common.PURCHASE_ORDER))&(~bdf.CHANNEL.isin(common.CHANNEL))&(~bdf.SHIP_TO.isin(common.SHIP_TO))&(~bdf.PROD_LINE.isin(common.PROD_LINE))&(~bdf.GROUP_NUMBER.isin(common.GROUP_NUMBER))&(~bdf.DESCRIPTION.isin(common.DESCRIPTION))&(~bdf.ITEM.isin(common.ITEM))&(~bdf.ORDER_QTY.isin(common.ORDER_QTY))&(~bdf.FW_END_DT.isin(common.FW_END_DT))&(~bdf.BPS_INCLUDE.isin(common.BPS_INCLUDE))]



Out:
SITE    CUST    ORDER_NUMBER    ORDER_DATE  PURCHASE_ORDER  CHANNEL SHIP_TO PROD_LINE   GROUP_NUMBER    DESCRIPTION ITEM    ORDER_QTY   FW_END_DT   BPS_INCLUDE
```

Nothing doing

```
In:
(bdf == dftest).all().all()




Out:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-6c2f52f55e60> in <module>()
----> 1 (bdf == dftest).all().all()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in f(self, other)
   1611             # Another DataFrame
   1612             if not self._indexed_same(other):
-> 1613                 raise ValueError('Can only compare identically-labeled '
   1614                                  'DataFrame objects')
   1615             return self._compare_frame(other, func, str_rep)

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

They're not identically labelled?

When I tried searching around for the following I was suggested to try:

```
In:
bdf.eq(dftest)


Out:
    SITE    CUST    ORDER_NUMBER    ORDER_DATE  PURCHASE_ORDER  CHANNEL SHIP_TO PROD_LINE   GROUP_NUMBER    DESCRIPTION ITEM    ORDER_QTY   FW_END_DT   BPS_INCLUDE
0   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False
1   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False
2   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False
3   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False
4   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False
5   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
52995   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False
106050 rows × 14 columns
```

And in this case it looks like each pair of cells doesn't match... :(

Am I missing something totally obvious?

Comment: What does `(bdf.index == dftest.index).all()` print? If it's False, then the problem is that the index is not the same, so you could try `bdf.index = dftest.index` and try again.

Comment: It gave me an error originally. After I tried bdf.index = dftest.index it printed False.

Comment: `(bdf.index == dftest.index).all()` gave an error? What was it?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It initially printed False.

Comment: Ok, then isn't that good news? It means the comparison didn't work because the index wasn't the same.

Comment: Hmm, right. But after I tried `bdf.index = dftest.index` `(bdf.index == dftest.index).all()` printed True but I still have the same issue. `print(bdf.equals(dftest))` yields False for instance. 

It's strange because `(bdf.CUST== dftest.CUST).all()` is now True but `(bdf.ORDER_DATE == dftest.ORDER_DATE).all()` is False.

Comment: Perhaps there are leading/trailing whitespaces, NaNs, or something else. Anything could be the reason. Can't help you further without your data, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any nan / null / missing values in your data?

If so groupby.sum() can replace such values with e.g. 0. in case of numeric dtypes

If the above is the culprit, groupby.first() result would be identical to your original input

Comment: I don't have any null values.